# SQLCA.SQLERRD Host array in Pro*C

Tags: oracle, oracle-pro-c

As we know in numerous of the documentations it is mentioned that the 3rd element of the Host array `SQLCA.SQLERRD` i.e. `sqlca.sqlerrd[2]` contains the cumulative number of rows processed  by the SQL statement so far (in terms of Pro*C).

Does someone know of the significance of the other elements i.e. `[0]`,`[1]` and what they signify?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [error handling documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e10825/pc_09err.htm#g30970), they don't do anything; they're reserved for future use, though it's starting to look unlikely they'll actually ever be utilised. `sqlerrd` is declared as `long[6]`, but only `[2]` and `[4]` appear to be used, with the latter the offset into the SQL statement for a parse error.

It's interesting that they don't use [0], [1] or [3] though; wonder if they were used for something else in an earlier version. [This old informix link](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.sqlt.doc/sqltmst189.htm) has a similar structure with similar meanings for `[2]` and `[4]`, so might give a hint at what they expected to use the others for; but may be a meaningless coincidence...

[PostgreSQL seems to have the same structure](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ecpg-errors.html#ECPG-SQLCA), as does [DB2](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2z9.doc.sqlref%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fdb2z_sqlcommunicationsareaintro.htm), and [SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa225204%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) has something that looks related. It's starting to look suspiciously like a standard... albeit one that Oracle only partially adheres to.

Comment: In some older documents I see that they refer to `sqlerrd[3]` as the Number of records processed instead of `sqlerrd[2]`. Its also curious that "Why `[6]` why not more, or less?"

Comment: I remember the info in IBM url in the corner of my head, but now the "error handling" documentation has confused me. Its now like an array with only 2 elements in use which is not [0] and [1], but [2] and [4].

Comment: @Annjawn - is that in Oracle documents? I've seen references to it as an estimated number of rows after the parse, and the Informix link hints at something similar, but I don't think I've ever seen it in anything specifically Oracle-related. Would be interesting to see that if you can link to it.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the case - six elements but only two used. I don't know off-hand (but might check tomorrow if I remember) if the others are always zero, uninitialised, or might hold info that just isn't documented.

Comment: Honestly, I don't remember where I saw the info and that was one of the reason why I asked this question. But I will dig a little bit more to see if I can find any older references.

Answer (score -1):

From the "Informix Guide to SQL" (February 1998):

('First', 'Second', etc. because not all languages index arrays beginning with 0.)

First - After a successful PREPARE statement for a SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE statement, or after a select cursor is opened, this field contains the estimated number of rows affected.

Second - When SQLCODE contains an error code, this field contains either zero or an additional error code, called the ISAM error code, that explains the cause of the main error.  After a successful insert operation of a single row, this field contains the value of any SERIAL value generated for that row.

Third - After a successful multirow insert, update, or delete operation, this field contains the number of rows that were processed.  After a multirow insert, update, or delete operation that ends with an error, this field contains the number of rows that were successfully processed before the error was detected.

Fourth - After a successful PREPARE statement for a SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE statement, or after a select cursor has been opened, this field contains the estimated weighted sum of disk accesses and total rows processed.

Fifth - After a syntax error in a PREPARE, EXECUTE IMMEDIATE, DECLARE, or static SQL statement, this field contains the offset in the statement text where the error was detected.

Sixth - After a successful fetch of a selected row, or a successful insert, update, or delete operation, this field contains the rowid (physical address) of the last row that was processed.  Whether this rowid value corresponds to a row that the database server
returns to the user depends on how the database server processes a query, particularly
for SELECT statements.

Comment: The question is about Oracle but this answer seems to be about IBM Informix. Is there a relationship between the two that would make this answer relevant?

Comment: Sorry, did not notice your [Oracle] tag.  But if SQLCA is standard (or semi-standard), it is likely that you'll find similar features across database implementations.  And no, this is not from IBM Informix; it's from Informix _before_ it was bought out by IBM.